# Preserve single quotes with to_nice_yaml()

Tags: ansible

When I try to pipe my variable array through `to_nice_yaml` then the usual way of preserving single quotes (wrapping them in double quotes) produces multiple single quotes.

`test_playbook.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    some_test_param:
    - "'testy'"
  tasks:
  - name: Do stuff
    template:
      src: ~/test_template.j2
      dest: /home/remote_user/test_config.yml
      owner: remote_user
      group: remote_user
      mode: '600'
      lstrip_blocks: yes
```

`test_template.j2`

```
Test array goes here:
{{ some_test_param | to_nice_yaml }}
```

I expected the output to be

```
Test array goes here
- 'testy'
```

But instead it was

```
Test array goes here
- '''testy'''
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a string starts with a special character yaml does not need to quote strings.

This is also how `to_nice_yaml` works. To demonstrated, I have made a slight adjustment to your playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    some_test_param:
      - "true"
  tasks:
  - name: Do stuff
    debug:
      msg: "{{ some_test_param | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

Clearly here I expect `"true"` to be a string and not a boolean, and this is exactly what `to_nice_yaml` produces:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "- 'true'\n"
}
```

Notice that `'true'` is single quoted. Notice how it transforms my double quotes to single quotes - that is because it reads my variable as yaml, and then outputs it in its own way. And if I were to remove the quotes - as if I do need a boolean, the output would not be quoted:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    some_test_param:
      - true
  tasks:
  - name: Do stuff
    debug:
      msg: "{{ some_test_param | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

Outputs:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "- true\n"
}
```

I found a nice article on when to quote or not a string in yaml: http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html

So when you're creating a string with a quote as `"'testy'"`, it produces exactly that in the output, just with a single quote: '''testy''', this is the way for yaml to [preserve a single quote inside single quotes](https://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2534365).

tl;dr
`to_nice_yaml` produces exactly what it says - reads your variable as yaml and outputs it in a correct yaml format.

If you need to add quotes to your string, you would have to do it with an additional task, such as `replace` or `regex_replace` filter.

Comment: That makes sense, so the outermost `'`s are denoting it's a string and the middle `'`s are escaping the innermost ones?

Comment: @user12430166 exactly

Comment: It's a pitty that Ansible doesn't allow just to escape the single quotes with single quotes in the playbook like `''testy''`